# Changing the screen dimensions in Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm building a web app with Flutter, but I want to mimic an iPhone screen view. I know that resizing the window can sort of achieve this effect, but is there a way to wrap all the contents in a frame of a phone screen graphic, or change the dimensions of the MaterialApp so that it is contained within the screen dimensions of a phone and doesn't fill up the whole window?

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap `MaterialApp` in a `SizedBox` to restrict its size. Then you can use it anywhere you want just like a regular widget.

[example](https://codepen.io/pegasisforever/pen/dyGgGyV)

Comment: One problem with this approach is that navigation animation is being displayed on that empty aria around the app

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe the question is still actual for some of you.

[See my answer in the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020592/how-to-make-flutter-web-app-a-certain-size-and-keep-phone-dimensions/)