# Flutter - Can we use AspectRatio to mimic the entire app width similar to devices on wide desktop monitors?

Tags: flutter, aspect-ratio

In continuation of this issue [Changing the screen dimensions in Flutter web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882139/changing-the-screen-dimensions-in-flutter-web-app)

I was under the impression that we could use AspectRatio, and wrap the entire MaterialApp inside it to achieve a 16:9 (smartphone) type aspect ratio, but it has no effect. On the web, in a large desktop monitor, the app is stretched all the way out the screen.

I would like to avoid setting a hard limit like the answers recommend in the linked issue.

Can we use somehow AspectRatio to achieve the desired effect?